# Spring hibernate handling big html form

Tags: spring, hibernate, persistence, forms

I am using Spring + Hibernate, and I will have a HTML from that has like 100+ fields and I must store all these values to database in a **single** table.

They are all used in one big massive calculation.

How should I handle this, I thought about creating an Entity with 100 fields and setters, getters, but is there a nicer solution for it?

EDIT:

Everytime when someone submits form, a new row will be added, so eventually there will be tens of thousands of rows.

Comment: hibernate is an object oriented framework. the logic behind hibernate is mapping database fields to objects. on the other hand, do you think if your database design is normalized. because 100+ fields seem not to be normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its not about an HTML but about the data modeling.
Think about your data, who are the consumers of it, how and in which business flows you're going to query the data.
In general an entity with 100 fields is not a good idea because it should be mapped to one single table with 100 columns. Its just not maintainable.

Maybe all the data should be normalized and you can store pieces of it in different tables in db with foreign keys?

Hope this helps or at least will give you some direction to think about

Comment: What do you mean under not maintainable? It will just store int values, 100 of them.

Comment: yes, but it will create a table (if not created) with 100 columns and will put a single row of 100 columns, right? Ask your DBA what does he/she think about this table :) Its like a class with 100 data fields. Technically its permitted, but its not clean and possibly means that it should be refactored somehow. The same holds for DB... Understand?

Comment: Yes but every time someone submits form, the row will be saved with different data, so there will be thousands , ten thousands of rows.

Comment: Sure, that's true. All I'm saying is that its ok that the table has thousands of rows, however its not good when the table has hundreds of columns.

Comment: But basically all the 100 fields in database will hold a number value, which will be basically used in a huge calculation like : 1+2+3+4+5+6 +... +100, so there is no normalization, they all work as a group and should not be divided really..what you think about that?

Comment: Its just a matter of design, Its very hard to make a decision without knowing a business flows. For example: if you need a calculation, maybe it worth to calculate what you need in advance and just store the results of the calculation. I also didn't know that this kind of data can't be normalized/divided to groups. If you don't see another choice than using 100 columns in the same table, let it be so...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a `Map` in this case, because:

- You only want to store the fields as key-value elements.
- It is more flexible to add/remove fields in the future.

So, instead of having a table with 100 fields you will end with a table with 2 fields (3 if you want to include the form identifier or something like that) and 100 rows.

If many of the form fields are empty (sparse data) you could also save some storage space (it depends on the database you are using).

Comment: All form fields must be filled and will be used in calculation. So for each time someone fills form and saves it, a row with 100 fields wont be added, but 100 rows with few fields? Is that really better? For example when user does calculation 100 times, there wont be 100 rows, but 10 000 rows??